# Java - Immutable array thread-safety

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, immutability, java-memory-model

I have a question regarding the Java Memory Model. Here is a simple class presenting the problem:

```java
public class ImmutableIntArray {

    private final int[] array;

    public ImmutableIntArray() {
        array = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
    }

    // Will always return the correct value?
    public int get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

}
```

As far as I know the JMM guarantees that the value of final fields will be visible to other threads after construction. But I want to ensure that other threads will see the most recent version of data stored in the array after construction.

Of course the code above is just a simple example presenting the problem, actually I want to implement a simple cache for direct byte buffers and I wouldn't like to rely on some Collection classes. Currently I am using a ReentrantReadWriteLock to ensure the correct behaviour but I would like avoid it if it is possible.

Comment: `array` is decleared as `final`, you cannot modify it

Comment: You could also implement it as singleton(with array filling in private constructor), so there is a guarantee, that array will be filled and only after accessible from other classes.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand question... what post-construction modification is going on?  Can you provide a scenario you'd be worried about?

Comment: Seems using lock or synchronized is the only way to do what you want.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad you cannot reassign the array field to another instance, but you can change the actual values in the array such as array[9] = 25.

Comment: What "problem" are you referring to?

Comment: Changing the array isn't even relevant here. He just wants to know if the construction assignments will be visible post-construction (and as Andrzej says: "Yes")

Comment: Thank you for the comments. There is no post-construction modification. As @dlev pointed out I just want to know whether the values stored in the array will be visible to other threads immediately after construction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this example, everything <s>will be fine</s> (hmm, let's suspend judgement a bit).  Immutability is ambrosia when it comes to thread-safety - if a value cannot change, the majority of concurrency problems are immediately no longer a concern.

[Amir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419075/amir-raminfar) mentioned `volatile` which is generally useful - but the constructor also has similar semantics for `final` variables that ensure visibility.  See [JLS clause 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) for details - essentially the constructor forms a *happens-before* relationship between the write to the final variables and any subsequent reads.

**EDIT**: So you set the <s>values</s> reference to the array in the constructor, it's visible across all threads at that point, and then it doesn't change.  So we know all other threads will see the same *array*.  But what about the array's *contents*?

As it stands, array elements don't have any special semantics with regard to volatility, they're as if you just declared a class yourself something like:

```
public class ArrayTen {
    private int _0;
    private int _1;
    // ...
    private int _9;

    public int get(int index) {
       if (index == 0) return _0;
       // etc.
    }
}
```

So - another thread will only see these variables if we can do something to establish the *happens-before* relationship.  And if my understanding is correct this requires but a small change to your original code.

We already know that the setting of the array reference *happens-before* the end of the constructor.  An additional point which is always true, is that actions in one thread *happen-before* later actions in that same thread.  So we can combine these by setting the array fields first, and *then* assigning the final field, so as to get this transitive guarantee of visibility.  This will of course require a temporary variable:

```
public class ImmutableIntArray {

    private final int[] array;

    public ImmutableIntArray() {
        int[] tmp = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tmp[i] = i;
        }
        array = tmp;
    }

    // get() etc.
}
```

I think this is guaranteed to be safe, now that we've switched the seemingly irrelevant order of assignment and population.

But again, there might be something else I've missed which means the concurrency guarantees aren't as robust as hoped.  This question is to my mind an excellent example of why writing bulletproof multithreaded code is tricky, even when you think you're doing something very simple, and how it takes a lot of thought and caution (and then bugfixes) to get right.

Comment: Could you add the relevant langSpec-link here?

Comment: I know final fields are guaranteed to be initialized - which is the array definition.  Are the fields *inside* the array guaranteed to be initialized (to their assigned values, not 0) before the reference is returned (can't the optimizer choose when to return the reference otherwise)?

Comment: @X-Zero the interesting part is "It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are". But that itself isn't absolutely clear for me - I mean there's a situation in the code where the array itself is correctly initialized but its elements are still 0, I assume that the spec should be read in such a way to guarantee that we'll see the newest results, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: It is an interesting point - mainly because the spec doesn't cover it explicitly, and because arrays are primitives so you can't see how their "fields" are defined.  I agree it's not definitive, but on the other hand I suspect it has to "work", simply because otherwise you couldn't use arrays in concurrent environments (you can't redeclare them as volatile, for example).  Besides, at a lower level it's a contiguous block of memory (unlike objects), so all of the contents are "inside" the range of addresses that's guaranteed to be correctly updated by visibility.

Comment: ...though I'm not sure to what extent that's guaranteed by the spec (even though on current commodity hardware it doesn't make sense to do it any other way).  I also get a bad feeling about mixing high-level, language-based JLS guarantees with RAM-location based hardware guarantees, and assuming there's some sort of associativity relation there.

Comment: OK - after rereading various aspects of the spec there's nothing special about arrays at all, so I think my assumptions above were not correct.  And as such I don't believe the code, *exactly* as written, is guaranteed to do the right thing.  (I suspect it probably would work on just about every JVM, but that's not really the point when it comes down to these questions! :-))  I'll edit the answer to include my thoughts.

Comment: @Andrzej: I think you could first initialize the array (hold in a local variable), and then set the final field as the last step in the constructor. Then it would be guaranteed to viewed as initialized.

Comment: So is @jtahlborn's answer the way to go, or might the optimizer do funky tricks with that one, too?  I have a nagging suspicion that they might not be 'up-to-date'... although it would be good if it just 'worked', as expected

Comment: @X-Zero - @jtahlborn's answer is right (to the best of my knowledge), since the assignment to the final field at the *end* makes everything that comes before it visible too.  The write is a sort of memory pivot that establishes a consistent cross-thread ordering - Jeremy Manson calls it the "two cones" [here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) (in this context `final` implies `volatile`).

Comment: Here is an old post which confirms that the code in the question effectively thread-safe with no need to do any additional tricks. http://tech.puredanger.com/2008/11/26/jmm-and-final-field-freeze/

Comment: @denis Interesting, especially the JCIP quote "any variables that can be *reached* through a final field... (such as the elements of a final array... ) are also guaranteed to be visible to other threads."  It's a shame that the formal definition wasn't posted as I wasn't aware that the JMM made this guarantee (or by what mechanism/rule it happens).

Comment: @Andrzej As mentioned in the comments this guarantee was described in original JSR133 spec - Figure 22: Transitive guarantees from ﬁnal ﬁelds - http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf

Comment: @denis The quote from the blog doesn't seem to hold in the broad case.  In fact, Figure 21 of JSR133 shows "an example of where this can go wrong" - the code there seems equivalent to the code in the question, and lo and behold Thread 2 can see the "wrong" value of `r5`.  On the other hand Figure 22 shows something working, but *that*'s analogous to our proposed fix with a temp variable - it's the assignment of `r1` to `p` at the end (then the read of `p` by Thread 2) that avoids the problem in Figure 21.  On closer inspection then I don't believe it contradicts this answer.

Comment: Ok so the conclusion to this saga is that there is no definite answer?

Comment: +1: Thanks. You've helped me understand the JMM a little bit more.

Answer (score 3):

your example is not quite right.  in order to get the final field assurance, you need:

```
public ImmutableIntArray() {
    int tmparray = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tmparray[i] = i;
    }
    array = tmparray;
}
```

Comment: Well, according to my understanding of the specification I suppose you are right. But anyway, in my opinion the specification is very confusing. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: +1: I just ended up deriving this same ordering without noticing that you'd already posted it.

Comment: @Tamás - i completely agree about the spec.  notice that i didn't state what guarantees final might give, only how to exploit them. :)

Answer (score 2):

I do think that you're afforded the same semantics with an array as with a final reference to an object. The spec states

> A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.

It also says

> It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5

Answer (score 0):

I think your array changes will be visible with your ImmutableIntArray.
From my reading on JLS the [freeze] action should take place when constructor exits.
The use of a temp array I think is useless:

```
int tmparray = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tmparray[i] = i;
}
array = tmparray;
```

To obtain final field guaranties we will need a [freeze] somewhere before constructor exit:

```
int tmparray = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tmparray[i] = i;
}
array = tmparray;
[freeze]
```

Anyway, [freeze] leaves the gates open to reorder instructions above it, so we will have the same thing:

```
int tmparray = new int[10];
array = tmparray; 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tmparray[i] = i;
}
[freeze]
```

[freeze] is implemented to contain at minimum a [StoreStore]. This [StoreStore] barrier must be issued before the moment when instance constructed is published.

From [JSR-133 Cookbook](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html):

> You cannot move stores of finals within constructors down below a store outside of the constructor that might make the object visible to other threads. (As seen below, this may also require issuing a barrier). Similarly, you cannot reorder either of the first two with the third assignment in:
>         v.afield = 1; x.finalField = v; ... ; sharedRef = x;

And I think this is done by
[(JSR-133 Cookbook)](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html):

> Issue a StoreStore barrier after all stores but before return from any constructor for any class with a final field.

So we can't store in sharedRef before all other contructor stores are done.

You can search by: "Transitive guarantees from final fields" in [(JSR133 spec)](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf).