# Varargs, immutable array, and thread-safety

Tags: java, thread-safety

Hi all I have an immutable array implementation which looks like this:

```
public static final class FixedArray<T> {
    private final T[] array;
    public final int Length;

    @SafeVarargs
    public FixedArray(T... args) {
        array = args;
        Length = args.length;
    }

    public T Get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }
}

public static final class FixedIntArray {
    private final int[] array;
    public final int Length;

    public FixedIntArray(int... args) {
        array = args;
        Length = args.length;
    }

    public int Get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }
}

public static final class FixedLongArray {
    private final long[] array;
    public final int Length;

    public FixedLongArray(long... args) {
        array = args;
        Length = args.length;
    }

    public long Get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

Initially I'd thought that it is guaranteed to be thread-safe. But after reading [the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626079/java-immutable-array-thread-safety) regarding immutable arrays and the Java Memory Model, I believe alone, I can't be sure.

I've not used a defensive copy, with the contract that the calling code "does the right thing" (and as usual, if it doesn't follow the contract, the behavior is undefined).

The calling method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] ints = new int[10000];
    FixedIntArray fixed_ints = new FixedIntArray(ints);
    SendToThreadA(fixed_ints);
    SendToThreadB(fixed_ints);
    SendToThreadC(fixed_ints);
    SendToThreadD(fixed_ints);
    //caller (which is this method) does the right thing, ints goes out of scope without anyone trying to modify it.
}
```

I was wondering is the code above guaranteed to be thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK. You can require caller to "hand-off" the array to you. Caller can clone one if necessary.

Memory write is usually the most expensive thing in a program (sans external IO).

Not everybody is stupid. You only need to be defensive enough to protect your target user base.

Answer (score 3):

As we don't know what happens to the array (and its values) to which you store a reference, I think your classes would be much safer if the constuctors create a copy of the argument array and set the internal final reference to the copied array.

Comment: I do agree with you, however the code has the assumption that the calling method does the right thing, as I've listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196431/varargs-immutable-array-and-thread-safety/8196519#comment-10072091

Comment: @Pacerier, if the calling code does *not* change the array passed after calling the constuctor you are ok. That said, making a copy would not take too much time or resources so I would probably do it anyway just guard against a future maintainer who might not remember the preconditions to using these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can pass an array to a varargs method, you'd need to make a copy of the constructor input to ensure it can't be modified outside the class. Having done that, as long as you don't assign the `final` field until after all the values are assigned in the copy array, you should be fine because the assignment to the `final` field is guaranteed to happen before any read of that field from another thread.

So a constructor would look like:

```
array = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
```

Orrrr you could just use a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) and get a lot more power.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's meaningful to examine it for thread-safety, because it's missing even a more basic level of safety. Consider this method:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 3, 3 };

    final FixedIntArray threeThrees = new FixedIntArray(arr);

    System.out.println(threeThrees.Get(0)); // prints "3"
    System.out.println(threeThrees.Get(1)); // prints "3"
    System.out.println(threeThrees.Get(2)); // prints "3"

    arr[0] = arr[1] = arr[2] = 4;

    System.out.println(threeThrees.Get(0)); // prints "4"
    System.out.println(threeThrees.Get(1)); // prints "4"
    System.out.println(threeThrees.Get(2)); // prints "4"
}
```

The problem is that, when a method that takes `int...` (or `Object...` or `long...` or anything else), it can receive *either* an array that's implicitly constructed by the compiler (as would happen if you typed `new FixedIntArray(3,3,3)`), *or* an array that's explicitly passed in by the calling code (as I did above). In the latter case, the calling code can continue to modify the array that it passed in!

Comment: Heys I'm aware that the calling code can modify the array internally but of course the only alternative is to make a defensive copy (which isn't what I want in this implementation). I was more concerned about the `FixedIntArray` variable. If the creator method passed a `FixedIntArray` variable to other threads (and of course itself doesn't try to *hack* the code by using an array that has a *public* reference, or modifying the array passed in), is it guaranteed to be thread-safe?

Comment: @Pacerier: If the array that's passed in has been populated thread-safely, then yes. The constructor won't return until *after* (literally after -- there's a "happens-before") the array reference has been copied.

Comment: @Pacerier The point is that no, it's not _guaranteed_ to be thread-safe if you don't ensure that nothing else has a reference to the internal array. If you do not modify the internal array externally? Yes, it will be fine... but that's only _if_. It would be easy enough for someone to accidentally do something you don't intend if you don't do what's necessary to make the guarantees.

Comment: @ColinD I've updated the question to add more clarity because it seems like we are misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Pacerier Like I said, it'll be fine if there are no writes to the array. But copying the array so you can make an absolute guarantee isn't such a terrible cost.